# how to do report using List in C#?

Tags: crystal-reports, c#-4.0

I have a requirement to bind the list to the report .This list is getting the result by querying the 3 tables.Could anyone suggest any link or alternative to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

In case if you are using Crystal reports for Visual Studio it's simple: Go to database expert, you could see the option Project data -> .net objects.

[image]